# Clear or hide old remote kernel connections and use local (or selected interpreter) kernel by default

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

Using Windows 10, remote server is Linux

I had set up VSCode to be able to use kernels from a JupyterHub server (there are two in the image, "Python 3" and "venv"), but have since found I prefer using the Remote-SSH extension to develop directly on the server. I want to get rid of this long list of kernels available when editing a notebook or interactive .py file in VSCode:

[image: long kernel list]

It's additionally annoying because the selected kernel defaults to the first kernel in the list, which doesn't have all the dependencies I need, so I *always* see an import error. This environment is managed by my IT so I can't just alter it or install what I need there.

I would love to just get rid of the remote kernels entirely and just use local kernels (shown by clicking the `Connect to Local Kernels` option in the image), or at least show the local kernels by default. **Ideally, the selected Python interpreter would *always* be automatically selected as the kernel**.

Things I've tried:

- Deleting the remote URI `> Jupyter: Specify Jupyter Server for Connections`. VSCode let me delete all but one URI.
- `> Jupyter Filter Kernels` doesn't save my selections half the time, and it never changes `jupyter.kernels.filter` in `settings.json`, so this has never had an effect on the kernels that are listed.
- Reinstalling the Jupyter extension
- Reinstalling the Jupyter extension and deleting it's `C:\myuser\.vscode\extensions` folder
- Searching for other places this connection data might be stored but found nothing

Comment: I can see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters) that Microsoft suggests to add `"python.defaultInterpreterPath"` in `settings.json`, to point to the path of the interpreter you prefer to be used as default. Perhaps you can try this option and see how it works for you.